# Check if position in array already filled with try catch in java?

Tags: java

for example that array[1,1] is 1 and if user want to input a number in array[1,1] the program gonna tell the user that array[1,1] is already filled with number and tell user to put the number somewhere else and i must use try catch for that problem.

i'm going to use that in my simple tic tac toe game

Comment: `try`/`catch` wouldn't be appropriate for this. Use an `if`.

Comment: should not really use `try/catch` to drive program logic

Comment: Is using `try` and `catch` an actual requirement of your assignment, or something you came up with?

Comment: Use an `if` to throw a subclass of `RuntimeException` if the array is filled, perhaps your own custom `ArrayFilledException`, and then catch it with a `try/catch`. Note that this is not actually good practice; I'm only recommending this because you seem to be required to use a `try/catch`.

Answer (score 0):

Make your array as `final` so you could assign the value once and the array value can't be initialized again.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Object` type array as you want's to store numbers and number can be zero or not zero positive / negative as well. `Object` type array will give you a benefit to check array location is null or not as default value for Object is null.

check this

```
class ArrayTest{
//Your Array
public static Object myArray[][] = new Object[2][2];

public static void main(String args[]){
    //set myArray[1][1] to some value to satisfy your question.
    myArray[1][1] = 10;
    myArray[1][0] = null;
    //Now you wants to take input from user and as per logic it should be assign to the array location which is empty or not used.
    //take input from user
    //.......
    //.......
    int userInput = 11;
    // say array location 1,0 is empty, asign it to myArray[1][0]
    int row = 1, col = 0;
    //finding empty location
    //if isNull result is true, it means array location is empty else not empty.
    if(isNull(row,col)){
        myArray[row][col] = (Object)userInput;
    }else{
        try{
            int[][] newRow_COl = findNewLocation();
            if(newRow_COl == null){
                System.out.println("Array is full");
            }else{
                myArray[newRow_COl[0][0]][newRow_COl[0][1]] = userInput;
            }
        }catch(Exception e){
            //catch caused exception.
        }
    }
}

//This function wll return true if the array location is empty else false.
private static Boolean isNull(int row,int col){
    System.out.println(myArray[0][0]);
    if(myArray[0][0] == null)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
//This function will return not-null array if the logic found any empty location.
//else it will return null.
private static int[][] findNewLocation(){
    int newLocation[][] = null;
    //.....
    //logic to find new location
    //....
    //....
    //if you could find the new location
    newLocation = new int[1][1];
    newLocation[0][0] = 1; //new row location
    newLocation[1][1] = 1; //new col location
    //....

    //if you dont have any new location then
    //return newLocation as it is null

    return newLocation;
}
```

}